# Shared volume across multiple docker-compose projects

Tags: performance, docker, docker-compose, composer-php, yarnpkg

I'm using `docker-compose` to orchestrate containers for multiple separate projects. Each of these projects has their own set of containers and do not relate to other projects.

For example:

```
/my-projects/project-1/docker-compose.yml
/my-projects/project-2/docker-compose.yml
/my-projects/project-3/docker-compose.yml
```

These projects are, however, similar in that they are all PHP projects and use webpack for front-end assets, thus share the same package managers: `composer` and `yarn`.

I was wondering, in the interest of performance, if it would be possible to mount a shared volume outside the directory root of all the projects for package manager caches?

For example:

```
/my-projects/caches/composer
/my-projects/caches/npm
/my-projects/project-1/docker-compose.yml
/my-projects/project-2/docker-compose.yml
/my-projects/project-3/docker-compose.yml
```

Where `/my-projects/caches/composer` and `/my-projects/caches/npm` get mounted inside the relevant containers within each project. In case it's not clear, only one project would be spun up at a time.

At the moment, if two projects share the same deps then each downloads and caches it individually. A more performant (in terms of build times) would be to mount a common volume and point the package manager's caches there so that when "Project A" downloads an update to a dip, "Project B" can load it from cache.

Comment: If you intend to use a bind mount - then just mount it. There is no additional configuration, just bind-mount one directory in as many containers as you like.

Comment: Thanks @anemyte! To my knowledge mounts described in the docker-compose file are relative/restricted to the root of the project - these would be directories outside of the project.

Comment: Wonderful, I missed that! I'll experiment and see what works. In these projects `composer.json` etc aren't available at image build time so are run as a separate build process. Thank you all.

Comment: Both absolute and relative paths (via `..`) work. It is Dockerfile that is restricted to a certain context root, not docker-compose.yml.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this is all very useful - I was indeed confused between Dockerfile limitations and docker-compose [lack] of limitation in this regards. @NicoHaase that is useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply mount the same directories as volume binds on each of the containers that require it. You [can use absolute paths](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volumes). Even one of the examples in the docs is using an absolute path as bind mount.

However, volumes are not available during image build (`docker-compose build`, which is where commands like `composer install`, `npm install` or `yarn install` should be run in any case.

Although if you are running these commands at container runtime, nothing stops you from mounting these cache dirs into each container.